# Is it OK to have nodes with mixed major versions running for months?

Tags: upgrade, cassandra

We are planning to upgrade to Cassandra 4 (currently on 3.x).

The question is -> Is it ok for Cassandra cluster to run for extended periods (months) in a mixed mode. Like some datacenters Cassandra 4.0.x and some Cassandra 4.1.x? If not allowed, what is the worst thing can happen?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify - are you asking about the case of mixing 3.x and 4.x? Or about the case of mixing 4.0.x and 4.1.x?

Answer (score 7):

We do not recommended running a cluster in "mixed mode", specifically where nodes are running different major versions of Cassandra for longer than 1 or 2 days.

There is a long list of operational limitations you will run into while the cluster is in mixed mode. They include the following:

- Inability to perform schema changes since schema versions between major versions are incompatible.
- Inability to `TRUNCATE` tables.
- Inability to perform any operation that requires streaming including repairs, topology changes (node additions, decommissions) and bulkloads with `sstableloader`.

These limitations will be very challenging in a production environment since they will hamper your ability to maintain the optimal performance of your cluster. For example, if you encounter a hardware failure then you will not be able to bootstrap the node back into the cluster until all nodes have been upgraded.

We recommend that you at least upgrade the binaries on all nodes in all DCs. You can then delay the SSTable upgrades until such time that you are able to schedule them. Cheers!

Comment: Erick, I cannot comment since I don't have enough points or whatever, but you are talking about major versions and this is not the question. This is a question between 4.0 and 4.1, aka a minor version. I very strongly suspect the answer is the same for minor versions, but this might help clarify for folks what you are saying.

Comment: The question *is* about major versions `We are planning to upgrade to Cassandra 4 (currently on 3.x).`

Comment: That's not correct @DougWhitfield.  The post specifically asked about v3 to v4. Cheers!

Comment: @ErickRamirez The post mentions upgrading from v3 to v4, but is asking about running mixed 4.0 and 4.1.

Comment: @MartinSmith note that OP never said "major versions", [that was added by Erick Ramirez](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/330282/revisions) (who wrote this answer). Also I don't read "Like some datacenters Cassandra 4.0.x and some Cassandra 4.1.x" as OP mentioning what somebody else is doing in passing - I read it as OP giving an example of what they mean by "a mixed mode".

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not recommended to stay on mixed-versions within a single cluster for many months. One downside, among other things, to consider running mixed mode cluster versions is below,

> Propagation of schema changes between mixed version nodes might have unexpected results. Therefore, you should take action to prevent schema changes for the duration of the upgrade process.

For the full list of upgrade steps, please see [this documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/luna-cassandra/docs/guides/upgrade/overview.html). Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

So as Madhavan alluded, this is what is known as "upgrade mode."  Essentially, yes, it is possible to have the nodes in a cluster run on more than one version.

However, if the clusters support different versions of the binary protocol, the connecting applications will sometimes connect to an older node and sometimes to a newer one.  This means that they will likely negotiate connections at different protocol versions, which can be problematic.  That's why we recommend forcing applications to connect to the *lower* of the two protocol versions if this period will last a while.

There will also be issues with data streaming and replication, as the schema versions won't match.  This also means that things like repairs and hinted handoffs cannot be completed.

In short; possible? "Yes."

Recommended?  "No."